# fprintf/fputs vs cout performance for large strings

Tags: c++, c

When I made tests on `fprintf()`, `fputs()`, and `ofstream operator (<<)`, I realized C functions(both) offer better run-time performance, but when input strings get larger, both C functions run slower than C++'s operator.

I wonder the reason of bad performance of C++ on small strings, and the reason why it outperforms the C for larger strings.

Appreciate it.

Note: Unfortunately, I couldn't share the strings for size 1000+ chars.

**Test Results**

```
- String Size -> 20 chars, C++(<<): 0,80 C(fprintf): 0,50 C(fputs):
   0,20
- String Size -> 50 chars, C++(<<): 1,06 C(fprintf): 0,80 C(fputs):
   0,35
- String Size -> 1000 chars, C++(<<): 6,39 C(fprintf): 8,35 C(fputs):
   5,01

-  String Size -> 2000 chars, C++(<<): 12,33 C(fprintf): 16,84 C(fputs):
   9,06

-   String Size -> 50000 chars, C++(<<): 0,20 C(fprintf): 0,39 C(fputs):
   0,27 (1000 runs instead of 1 million runs)

-   String Size -> 100000 chars, C++(<<): 0,40 C(fprintf): 0,45 C(fputs):
   0,74 (1000 runs instead of 1 million runs)
```

**Here is the code**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>
#include "Stopwatch.h"

using namespace std;

void testNewline(string test_str,int run){
    StopWatch timer;
    ofstream outdata("writeToFile-CPP-newline.txt");
    timer.start();
    for (int i = 0 ; i < run ; i++){
        outdata << i << ":" << test_str << "\n";
    }
    timer.stop();
    outdata.close();
    cout << "C++ Time spent:  - " << timer.seconds() << endl;
}

int main() {
    int run = 1000000;
    string test_str(str100);
    size_t len = test_str.length();
    cout << "Write File - " << run << " Runs\n";
    cout << "Length is " << len << " chars\n";

    testNewline(test_str,run);

    return 0;
}
```

**Stopwatch.h - Cpp**

```
#include <time.h>
#ifndef STOPWATCH_H_
#define STOPWATCH_H_

#define str20 "a very long literal "
#define str50 "a very long literal string a very very long string"
#define str100 "a very long literal string a very very long stringa very long literal string a very very long string"
#define str1000 ...
#define str2000 ...
#define str50000 ...

class StopWatch{
private:
    clock_t start_;
    clock_t end_;
    bool isRunning_;
public:
    void start(){
        start_ = clock();
        end_ = 0;
        isRunning_ = true;
    }

    void stop(){
        if(isRunning_){
            end_ = clock();
            isRunning_ = false;
        }
    }

    double seconds() const
    {
        return double (end_ - start_) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    }

    StopWatch(): start_(), end_(), isRunning_() {}
};    
#endif /* STOPWATCH_H_ */
```

**WriteFile.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "Stopwatch.h"

int main(void) {

    const int run = 1000000;
    int i;
    size_t len = strlen(str100);
    char *test_str = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*(len+1));
    strcpy(test_str,str100);

    FILE *file = fopen("writeToFile-C.txt","w");
    clock_t start_ = start();
    for (i = 0; i < run ; i++){
        fputs(test_str,file);
    }
    clock_t end_ = stop();
    fclose(file);

    printf("Write File - %d Runs\nString Length is %d chars\nC (fputs) Time spent: %.2f seconds\n",run,len,seconds(start_,end_));

    FILE *file2 = fopen("writeToFile-C-2.txt","w");
    clock_t start2_ = start();
    for (i = 0; i < run ; i++){
        fprintf(file2,"%d:%s\n",i,test_str);
    }
    clock_t end2_ = stop();
    fclose(file2);

    printf("Write File - %d Runs\nString Length is %d chars\nC (fprintf) Time spent: %.2f seconds\n",run,len,seconds(start2_,end2_));

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**StopWatch.h - C**

```
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#ifndef STOPWATCH_H_
#define STOPWATCH_H_

#define str20 "a very long literal "
#define str50 "a very long literal string a very very long string"
#define str100 "a very long literal string a very very long stringa very long literal string a very very long string"
#define str1000 ...
#define str2000 ...
#define str50000 ...  

clock_t start(){
    return clock();
}

clock_t stop(){
    return clock();
}

double seconds(clock_t start, clock_t end)
{
    return (double) (end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
}

#endif /* STOPWATCH_H_ */
```

I used MinGW Compiler.

Compile code for C++ : g++ -O3 -Wall -c
Compile code for C: gcc -O3 -Wall -c

Edit: I am not worried about the insignificant difference for small strings, but it is an academic curiosity.

Comment: `strlen` in C Strings needs to read every character, looking for a null. C++ string classes can store a value for the length. This means that `strlen` in C runs in O(N) time, but for C++ strings it can use a slower, but O(1) operation.

Comment: In addition to @Dragonthoughts's comment, keep in mind that `cout` does not simply get to read the size of the string and then print it - `cout` needs to deal with string in an object-oriented way (i.e. it has to check if you are printing any `int`s or `float`s etc.). `[f]puts()` does no such thing - it simply iterates over every `char` in the string until it reaches a null-terminator (`'\0'). Due to this, it makes sense that for small strings, simply iterating over all 1000 (c string functions) or so characters is faster then doing all the complex object-oriented operator-overloading ...

Comment: ... magic C++ must  perform - but there comes a point where going over 2000 characters is much slower than the background work c++ performs on strings.

Comment: @Ankush there is nothing object-oriented here. It's all about overloading and compile-time decisions.

Comment: @n.m I believe the c++ printing functions use inheritance, so they end up passing objects around (may be wrong).

Comment: @Ankush indeed your belief is wrong.

Comment: @Ankush why is finding string length is important? Is it something about allocation space for stream?

Comment: String length is important because, at least in c, "strings" are nothing more than a contagious array of bytes (`char []`). This means the characters in the string are all next to each other in memory. In order to output the string, `fputs()` will assume the `char *` pointer you pass it points to the first character, and it will print that character, then advance to the next character (byte) in memory. If the function didn't know the string length, how would it know when to stop advancing in memory!

Comment: @Dragonthoughts in order to print n characters, you need to go through n characters. There's nothing O(1) in it.

Comment: @n.m. if it is not the cost of finding length, what is the reason of C becoming worse for larger string compared to C++?

Comment: I guess it *is* because of the cost of finding length. You see, in order to copy a C string to a stream buffer, one needs to go byte by byte and check for 0 each time. Whereas with C++ strings, one can use a much more efficient block copying. Essentially it's `strcpy` vs `memcpy` difference. Both operations are O(n) but `memcpy` can me so more efficient (by a constant factor). But this is just a guess, you need to use a profiler in order to be able to tell for sure.

Comment: Note that every function in stdio are not design to focus performance, try `fwrite(test_str, 1, len, file)` I think it's would kill your stats ;)

Comment: @Stargateur I thought of that, too, but the advantage was not as great as I expected.  See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51149880/fprintf-fputs-vs-cout-performance-for-large-strings/51152268#51152268).

Answer (score 8):

This is an interesting question.  The question, restated, is: why are `fputs` and `fprintf` faster for short strings, while `<<` to `cout` is faster for longer strings?

I suspect, as suggested in some of the comments, that `<<` to `cout` is faster because C++ strings carry their size up-front and explicitly.  C-style strings, on the other hand, require scanning to find the terminating `'\0'`, which is an additional expense.

However, the overhead of `<<` and `cout` is greater, so its advantages are not seen for shorter strings.

I wrote another version of your program (attached below) and tried it on various string sizes and numbers of trials, with these results on my machine.  I also threw the stdio function `fwrite` into the mix.

```
string length   trials       cout     fprintf  fputs    fwrite
10              100000000    9        8        8        7
100             100000000    10       9        8        8
1000            100000000    14       17       18       12
10000           10000000     6        10       10       6
100000          1000000      4        10       9        4
1000000         1000000     11        72       71       10
10000000        100000       7        95       94       8
```

Presumably the important distinction is that `fprintf` and `fputs` have to print the characters *while simultaneously checking each one to see whether it's `\0`*.  `cout` and `<<`, on the other hand, like `fwrite`, know the count of characters up front, and so can blindly write exactly that many.

The power and flexibility of `cout` and `<<` come at a (small) price, but it seems to be a one-time cost, per "call" rather than per character written.

And then `fwrite`, which also knows the count up front, does just as well as `cout`, or better.  It looks like `cout` somehow ekes out a win on the last, hugest trial, which is a bit of a surprise.  It may just be because every call to `fwrite` has to pass four arguments, and `fwrite` has to do an extra multiplication of `nels` × `elsize`.

But with all of this said, any time we're examining performance, it's important to remember that *If you have to perform millions of carefully-controlled trials just to detect a small difference, the difference probably doesn't matter in practice*.  Use the style of i/o that's most natural for you, the problem you're solving, and the language you're using.  Unless you're writing a high-performance program that's i/o intensive, it probably won't matter which i/o calls you use.

In particular, I cheated: I ran all of my trials with standard output redirected to /dev/null, to minimize the i/o time, and maximize any actual computational differences between the four methods under test.  If the output had been "real" -- to a file, pipe, or network stream -- I suspect it would have dominated the performance, and I would have had to perform many more trials to show any difference between the methods.

Finally, here's the program I used:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int n = atoi(argv[1]);
    int m = atoi(argv[2]);
    char *p = (char *)malloc(n);
    memset(p, 'x', n-2);
    p[n-2] = '\n';
    p[n-1] = '\0';
    std::string s = p;
    int i;
    time_t t1, t2, t3, t4, t5;

    t1 = time(NULL);
    for(i = 0; i < m; i++)
        std::cout << s;
    t2 = time(NULL);
    for(i = 0; i < m; i++)
        fprintf(stdout, "%s", p);
    t3 = time(NULL);
    for(i = 0; i < m; i++)
        fputs(p, stdout);
    t4 = time(NULL);
    for(i = 0; i < m; i++)
        fwrite(p, 1, n, stdout);
    t5 = time(NULL);

    fprintf(stderr, "cout %ld ",    t2-t1);
    fprintf(stderr, "fprintf %ld ", t3-t2);
    fprintf(stderr, "fputs %ld ",   t4-t3);
    fprintf(stderr, "fwrite %ld\n", t5-t4);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for restating and the code! Could you give more information about overhead of << and cout?

Comment: What platform are you using? `time` works differently on Windows from most Unixes.

Comment: @MerveKantarcı No, I can't, and that's the weakest part of my answer.  Blaming "the OOP overhead" is a convenient and popular excuse, and it does sometimes have some merit, but well-written OOP code needn't be that much more expensive.  I don't know enough about the internal mechanics of C++ iostreams to know what sorts of unavoidable startup overhead these calls might have.

Comment: @n.m. MacOS.  (What's different about `time()` on Windows?)

Comment: `std::time` on Windows measures wall time while on Unixes it's CPU time. You are measuring CPU time. It doesn't take into account IO time. Try timing your program with the `time` shell command (or a stopwatch!) to see the difference. Also, the functions you are comparing are apples and oranges (some are formatted output and some are not). std::ostream::write is very likely to have identical performance to std::write. Also, the overhead of iostreams has nothing to do with object orientation (C stdio is *also* object-oriented, believe it or not).

Comment: overhead from OOP is often cause by people who don't care about perf, or because there just use it badly, `cout` has a very good design and I think the overhead is zero. It doesn't surprise me that fwrite have the same perf than cout. (Note: that your test is not precise use `clock_gettime` would give you an accurate time with monotonic clock.) (for example: `./a.out 10000000 100000 > /dev/null` give me `cout 1 fprintf 251 fputs 251 fwrite 0`)

Comment: @n.m. No, `time()` under Unix measures wall time as well.  But your point about CPU vs. i/o time is well taken, and I'm addressing it in an update to my answer.

Comment: @MerveKantarcı Don't miss the update I just added, two paragraphs at the end beginning with "any time we're examining performance, it's important to remember".

Comment: @Stargateur Good points abut OOP.  `time()` should be fine, though, as long as the measured times are substantially greater than 1s, and the clock wasn't changed (or the system put to sleep) between measurements.  (But, yes, normally I'd use `gettimeofday` or `clock_gettime`.  But I was in a hurry here.)

Comment: While your explanation is right about searching for '\0' takes time, your test is a little bit far from real usage. I mean, the OS needs to process the given data, which usually takes significantly more time than the search for '\0' (I suppose that you redirected stdout to /dev/null, which means the the OS doesn't have to do anything with the data). If I measure the fastest possible OS processing, writing to ramdisk, the difference is "just" 20% for 100MB blocks: `fwrite` is 20% faster than `fputs` (on a linux machine).

Comment: @SteveSummit Sorry, you are right, I was thinking about `clock`, not `time`.

Comment: FWIW, 99% of (userland) **CPU** time your program takes is spent in `strlen` (as profiled with valgrind/callgrind).

Comment: @n.m. My program, or the OP's?  (I didn't call `strlen` directly, and I wouldn't expect any indirect calls to it, either.)

Comment: @Stargateur Notwithstanding your points about OOP, we do still have the curious result (as shown in the OP's timings, and mine) that `<<` to `cout` is somehow a little slower for small strings.  That result seems significant, and if it's not "OOP overhead", what is it?  (I don't know.)

Comment: Your program. strlen is called from fputs.

Comment: @n.m. So I think you mean, `strlen` is called from *your system's implementation* of `fputs`.  (I don't know for sure about mine, but obviously it's possible to implement `fputs` without calling `strlen`.)

Comment: Yes. Obviously not all implementations do that, mine is glibc. But all implementations will have to do something very simiilar.

Comment: About the overheads: the main one is probably that of *[synchronising with stdio](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/sync_with_stdio)*. Try disabling it.

Comment: @SteveSummit if the input is small the time will be fast, don't worried about little differences for these case, just worried about performance for big input.

Comment: @Stargateur I'm not worried about it, and in my answer I encouraged the OP not to worry about it.  But you have to admit we do have a discrepancy between the statement "`cout` is just as fast, there's no 'OOP overhead'", and the data in front of us.

Comment: @SteveSummit Don't forget that cout is not an equivalent of fwrite, it's not possible to compare then as they do not do exactly the same thing.

Comment: @Stargateur Sure.  But for small sizes, it looks like `fputs` and `fprintf` are faster, too.  I do want to investigate n.m's observation involving stdio synchronization

Comment: Most significant lines of the answer *"it's important to remember that If you have to perform millions of carefully-controlled trials just to detect a small difference, the difference probably doesn't matter in practice."* `:)`